# what is this piece of code doing? javascript basic

Tags: javascript

Im learning javascript and im stuck with something i couldnt know how it works, im working in how to serialize a form into a json string so i found this tutorial.

https://code.lengstorf.com/get-form-values-as-json/

and im trying to understand the code but im stuck in this part.

```
const formToJSON = elements => [].reduce.call(elements, (data, element) => {
    data[element.name] = element.value;
    return data;
}, {});
```

i dont understand what are those lines doing or how they work even with the tutorial explanation. For the basic i had already study of javascript i cant recognize the sintax of the code, can someone please explain it to me.

Regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is ES6 Syntax, with an arrow-function its just creates a function `formToJSON` which can convert an array of the simplest form:

```
[
  {name: 'field_1', value: 1},
  {name: 'field_2', value: 2},
]
```

to:

```
{
  field_1: 1,
  field_2: 2
}
```

which is used to send the form data.. for example..